# Same path but different guard

Tags: angular, routes

The Base Component (`MainFrameComponent`/`AuthComponent`) of my Application changes if a User is logged in.
I have some Components that I want to implement in both views.
For example:

if logged in:

`localhost:4200/about-us` is displayed inside the `MainFrameComponent`

else:

`localhost:4200/about-us` is displayed inside the `AuthComponent`

The routes that should be always accessible are inside of `OPEN_ROUTES`.

app-routing.module.ts:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: MainFrameComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [...MAIN_ROUTES, ...OPEN_ROUTES]},
  {path: '', component: AuthComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard], children: [...AUTH_ROUTES, ...OPEN_ROUTES]},

  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''},
];
```

If I try to open `/about-us` when not logged in, nothing happens because the route is blocked by the first guard and the second route is not even considered by Angular.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you cannot have two routes definitions with the same path. Only the first one would be used. I think you have a few repeats by looking at how you used `...OPEN_ROUTES`.

I suggest you split your routes in a different way, and to add a third guard type for the OPEN_ROUTES.

Something like this should get you started (please mind that the order of the route configurations is important):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'your-landing-page-logged-on', pathMatch: 'full' },
  ...OPEN_ROUTES.map(x=> {
     x.canActivate = [OpenRoutesGuard];
     return x;
  }),
  ...AUTH_ROUTES.map(x=> {
     x.canActivate = [LoginGuard];
     return x;
  }),
  {path: '', component: MainFrameComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [...MAIN_ROUTES]},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''},
];
```

Also, make sure you don't have many `pathMatch: 'full'` in our route configs. Having too many of them is usually a sign you have to rearrange them.

Comment: The thing is that I want to display the `/about-us` INSIDE the `MainFrameComponent` / `AuthComponent`. This way the `OPEN_ROUTES` are on their own and not the children of the specified Parent Component

Comment: you cannot have the same route twice, but you could have a copy of the same route structure twice. As long as they have a different route parent it would work.